# InDesign: grep style to move single i words to next line

Tags: adobe-indesign, automation, paragraph-styles, grep, formatting

I need a Grep style in my paragraph styles in InDesign that makes sure that the letter `i` cannot stand alone at the end of a line, but will always move to the beginning of the next line. I have a client that makes me do it manually.

Comment: Why only "i"? But anyway. Just instruct to Find: (\d+)( )(i)
replace: $1~S$3  
But I would suggest to use script or regular ctr+f as it will change in every instance not only the ones with GREPed style.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY I do it with *a/A* as well, and sometimes two-letter words. Itty-bitty words at the end of a line can sometimes look untidy, and I completely understand the impulse to bump them down to the beginning of the next line.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I Use a script called "UseMyTypo". It can add nonbreaking space after given letters or words as well as remove extra ones etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Create a character style and set it to "No break".
- Edit your existing paragraph style, go to the GREP Style tab, choose the character style you created above and type `(?<=\s)i\W+` in the "To Text" field. (credits go to @Tobias Kienzler who suggested this)

[image: no break]

[image: grep style]

Comment: Although you dont need a separate style for different letters you can use the `(i|a|a,)` syntax to enumerate many options. But good thing  about the images, clarified this quote much (even though i had voted and tested this before you got them posted for me to see).

Comment: Correct, the GREP can be improved to deal with multiple issues at the same time.

Comment: If I understand this right, it could probably also be expanded to handle any single-letter word with something like `\s[A-Za-z]\s`

Comment: @IMSoP better to use the `\w` class than `[A-Za-z]` in that case, its neater and includes all word characters

Comment: So `\s\w,?\s` should probably work with any single-letter word, with or without a trailing comma?

Comment: @joojaa Yeah, I was being conservative because I don't know what flavour of regex the tool uses, and `[...]` character classes are more portable, but if `\w` is available, it's definitely neater. :)

Comment: You can also use `(?<=\s)i\W+` (or `(?<=\s)\w\W+`). The lookbehind `(?<=` makes sure the preceding whitespace _remains_ breakable, otherwise your GREP-style might pull the previous syllable down, too. And `\W+` means at least one non-word character, which takes care of punctuation as well.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler yes thats actually way better.

Comment: Hopefully the OP is following these comments and can choose whichever string works best with their document. I am definitely adding this to my own collection of Grep strings. Quite useful comments thanks! :)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Using the  `\s\w,?\s` made the word before jump down as well. `(?<=\s)i\W+` worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great. If you feel this helped, please take a moment to approve and upvote the answer above. Tnx

Comment: @Lucian It would make sense to edit the answer to contain what helped Christina, otherwise accepting the answer would be misleading - and I don't want to post another answer just to steal the tick ;)

Comment: By the way, a nice tool to check and understand GREP-styles (and RegEx in general) is https://regex101.com/

Comment: You are right and I edited my post. I hesitated to do so initially because i was thinking long-term about people visiting this via google search, and wasn't sure if they will be looking for the basic or the advanced string. In any case your string resolves the issue better, so I included it in my post. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First make a no break character style like in Lucian's asnwer, then try this Grep style in your paragraph style. It worked for me. `(?<=[!\?\.]\s)[^\s]{1,3}\s`

Comment: What is a 'broken character style'?

Comment: Sorry, "no break"

Comment: I took the liberty to clarify that a little. Be aware that because of up/downvotes, answers aren't always displayed in the same order. If you want to know more about the Stack Exchange model and specifically about this site, have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help]. Oh, and welcome! :D

Answer (score 0):

This solution works great: `(?<=\s)\w{1,3}\W+`
only that it won't work for when more than one 1-3 letter words are next to each other, in that case it will skip every other word.
I propose to add a second grep style to account for this `(?<=\s)\w{1,3}\W+\w{1,3}\W+` and can keep going to find 3,4,5.. 1-3 letter words together. There is probably a smarter DRY solution to that, but I'm not smart.