# GREP for non-breaking space after initials

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, grep

I'm laying out a bibliography in ID, and I need a way to insert a non-breaking space after initials, so A., B., etc. don't end up at the end of lines.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Find any uppercase, followed by a full stop and a space:

```
 (\u\.)\s
```

And replace with the same letter and full stop, followed by a non-breaking space:

```
 $1~S
```

Or see my other answer [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/84524/62949) which describes a different solution to a similar situation.

Comment: Alternative: a GREP style that applies No Break – a fire-and-forget method.

Answer (score -2):

Figured it out:

Find:

```
(A.|B.|C.|D.|E.|F.|G.|H.|I.|J.|K.|L.|M.|N.|O.|P.|Q.|R.|S.|T.|U.|W.|X.|Y.|Z.)(\s)
```

Change to:

```
$1~S
```

Comment: This is _very_ inefficient. You’re completely bypassing the whole concept and point of regular expressions. See Lucian’s answer for a much better and greppier way to do it.

Comment: The full stop will match *any* character after an uppercase. This will mess up your text.